# background image is not displaying correctly. it is small when it should be full size

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a background image that is not displaying correctly. What css properties can help me achieve a full size background image? I have already set the background-size: 100% 100%;
which doesn't help at all.

Here is an image of the background of how it looks on my project:
[image]

As you can see it is sort of smashed and not very visible.
This is how it is supposed to look:
[image]

```
    import styles from './style';
import { Navbar, CTA, BodyTop, BodyBottom, BodyMiddle, Footer } from './components';

const App = () => (
  <div className='w-full overflow-hidden'>
    <div className='bg-cta-gradient h-[400px]'>
      <div className={`flex-col background-img ${styles.paddingX} ${styles.flexCenter}`}>
        <div className={`mt-5 ${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          <Navbar />
        </div>
        <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}> 
          <CTA />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className={`bg-bodyColor ${styles.flexStart}`}>
      <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}> 
          <BodyTop />
          <BodyMiddle />
          <BodyBottom />
          <Footer />
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

css

```
   .background-img {
  background-image: url('./assets/bg-pattern-intro-desktop.svg') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using background-size: cover?

Comment: Did the answer solves this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `background-size: contain` will work for you.
Another option is `cover`.
You can check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size